# Is the distribution provisioning profile associated with the iPhone device?

Tags: iphone

I installed the distribution (for Appstore) provisioning profile in Xcode, but it doesn't show up under Devices, only the Developer provisioning profile shows up.  I cannot "Build and Go" with the distribution provisioning profile in Xcode either, however, "Build" does work.

Is this the correct behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. You can only use this profile to build App Store builds. For your testing you need a development profile. The distribution provisioning profile has nothing to do with the devices you registered on the iPhone development site.